# Android navigation: get the distance yet to travel

Tags: android, api, android-layout, navigation, locationmanager

The case: An android user has just set its destination in his standard android navigation application and chose the route (or alternate route) he wants to travel.

Is it possible for me to get the distance he currently has to travel, so I can use this in my app? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple on location change again find distance between your destination and your location.

and calculate distance between those points. this will give you distance yet to travel.

Comment: yes you have save your root somewhere and repeat calculating on similar route